# Intel AX200 WiFi not working Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi

I have recently installed an Intel AX200 wireless PCIe card into my desktop. I cannot get the card to work. I've read a bunch of other questions with similar issues, but haven't been able to fix it.

Here is some information:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

```
uname -r
5.8.0-43-generic
```

```
dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[   10.619859] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[   10.801937] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   10.801966] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22
[   10.801976] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   10.801978] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[   10.803139] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   10.823242] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[   11.262763] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[   12.290406] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5e52, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[   12.290422] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x80480218
[   12.290435] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x104
[   12.290439] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired.
[   12.290563] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   12.290565] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 6
[   12.290567] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode
[   12.290569] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
[   12.290571] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x002022F0 | trm_hw_status0
[   12.290572] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   12.290574] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x004FA34A | branchlink2
[   12.290575] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x004E4BBC | interruptlink1
[   12.290576] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x004E4BBC | interruptlink2
[   12.290578] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x004F3F8A | data1
[   12.290579] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00001000 | data2
[   12.290580] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[   12.290582] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   12.290583] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x0000FB61 | tsf low
[   12.290584] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   12.290585] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   12.290587] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00015B73 | time gp2
[   12.290588] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[   12.290589] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000037 | uCode version major
[   12.290591] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0xD9698065 | uCode version minor
[   12.290592] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000340 | hw version
[   12.290593] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00C89000 | board version
[   12.290595] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x8001FF03 | hcmd
[   12.290596] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0
[   12.290597] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   12.290599] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x08F00002 | isr2
[   12.290600] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[   12.290601] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   12.290602] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   12.290604] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x004F3F8A | wait_event
[   12.290605] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   12.290606] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000020 | l2p_duration
[   12.290608] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   12.290609] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   12.290610] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   12.290611] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   12.290613] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x0000F81C | flow_handler
[   12.290657] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   12.290659] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[   12.290660] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x20100222 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   12.290661] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   12.290663] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x80465826 | umac branchlink2
[   12.290664] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0xC0086AC0 | umac interruptlink1
[   12.290665] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   12.290667] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data1
[   12.290668] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2
[   12.290669] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[   12.290671] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000037 | umac major
[   12.290672] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0xD9698065 | umac minor
[   12.290673] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00015B65 | frame pointer
[   12.290674] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0xC0886ADC | stack pointer
[   12.290676] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   12.290677] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   12.290685] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[   12.290690] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x20000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   12.290694] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x80290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   12.290699] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   12.290704] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   12.290708] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   12.290713] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   12.290718] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   12.290722] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   12.290727] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   12.290734] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   12.290741] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   12.290748] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   12.290752] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   12.982729] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

```
lspci -nnk | grep Net -A3
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0084]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

The -110 error code seems to be where the problem is, but I don't know what it means or how to fix it. This card also has Bluetooth which is working.

EDIT: I've upgraded to the 5.10 kernel with no change.

```
uname -r
5.10.17-051017-generic
```

Answer (score 0):

Support for the AX200 is really hit or miss at times. That said, many people running the 5.10 kernel report that their Intel wireless cards are working properly and with a respectable data transfer rate.

If you would like to try upgrading your kernel to 5.10, read on …

#### Upgrading Your Kernel to 5.10

***Note:** All of the following commands are run from Terminal.*

First, let’s make sure your system is up to date:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Clean up the installed packages and apt a bit:

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean
```

Now let’s grab the 5.10 kernel. Well be putting the source files into `/tmp` as there’s no reason to hold onto them after installation. So:

```
cd /tmp
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10.17/amd64/linux-headers-5.10.17-051017_5.10.17-051017.202102170631_all.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10.17/amd64/linux-headers-5.10.17-051017-generic_5.10.17-051017.202102170631_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10.17/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.10.17-051017-generic_5.10.17-051017.202102170631_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10.17/amd64/linux-modules-5.10.17-051017-generic_5.10.17-051017.202102170631_amd64.deb
```

Next, we get to perform the installation:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Finally, reboot the system:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Once the system comes back up, check the kernel version in Terminal with `uname -r`.

If you’ve read this far, I hope this gets you a working network device

Comment: I've upgraded to 5.10 kernel following the above instructions, but still have no luck. Dmesg shows the same -110 error as before.